# What's the difference between 'eq' vs '==' in PHP?

Tags: php, string, operators, equality

First, I tried searching for different variations of the title I've put for this question, both on Stack Overflow and Google. I couldn't find a solution.

I am fairly new to PHP. New enough to not know the difference between using `eq` and `==` for string comparison!

I usually use `==` to compare strings in PHP. I am comfortable with it.

But I've seen code using `eq` to compare strings. And I vaguely remember someone making an observation like 'Oh! I used `==` to compare strings. I should have used `eq`'.

I just want to know whether using `==` is okay to do simple string comparisons? I am not talking about special cases, case-sensitive, substring or any fancy type of string comparison. Just checking whether `apple` is the same as `apple`.

Is `==` enough? or should I use `eq`.

---

My mistake :( thanks a lot for clearing my 'not-well-researched' question! It must have been Perl. I got confused seeing the code embedded inside HTML and thought it was a different way of embedding PHP. Sorry.

Comment: Ahem, are you sure you're coding in the right language? I know `eq` only from Perl and haven't seen it (includes the php.net docs) in PHP ever before.

Comment: The `eq` isn't even listed here: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: someone with a high enough rep can delete this question. I am unable to. I hope this question doesn't cause more confusion.

Comment: @senthil: this is in the standard perl documentation: type `perldoc perl` on the command line for a Table of Contents listing, where you will see that `perldoc perlop` covers the operators.

Comment: @senthil, PHP and Perl can look a lot alike--especially to a beginner.  Don't delete or request deletion for this question, it could be a big help to someone else.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php.. In the "parameters" section, the "operators" list has 'eq' in it!

Comment: Yes, but the parameter itself is a *string*. So it's just a keyword and no operator.

Comment: ahh!! its been a long time since I got *this* confused!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To accompany my comments: The `eq` operator in **Perl** tests for **string** equality, while the `==` tests for **numerical** equality only.

Even though PHP started once as a collection of Perl scripts, I don't think, they have copied this operator and [this page](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) seems to agree.

Comment: And in Bash the meaning of the two operators are reversed compared to Perl, that is "eq" is for numbers(?).

Comment: Or in other words, you could cover that as well in your answer.

Answer (score 11):

There is no `eq` operator in PHP. There is however `==` and `===`.

`===` is a strict comparison operator and won't do type conversion.

`==` will do type conversion (for example `'' == 0` evaluates to `true`).

See [Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for a full list and [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for the rules of PHP type conversion. The only reference I could find to `eq` was as an argument to [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php).

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn’t have an `eq` [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  You're probably thinking of Perl, where *eq* will compare two variables as strings.

PHP has an equality operator (`==`) and a true equality operator (`===`).  The true equality operator (`===`) will test that the expressions on each side of the operator are both equal, and of the same type.  The equality operator (`==`) will attempt to coerce each expression to the same type, and then compare them.

```
//this is true
'45' == 45

//this is false
'45' === 45
```

There are some cases where `==` will make bad guesses when it comes to types, so if you know you have two expressions of the same type, it's best to use `===`.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator checks if there's a perfect match between two variables, literals or a combination of these two programmatic entity ... but it is not type safe!

If you use it to compare strings, you are comparing a string with a regular expression to find a perfect match!

But there are a lot of most powerful way to compare strings in PHP. You need only know what you are trying to accomplish .... for example: `similar_text()`, `strcasecmp()`, `strcmp()`, etc. Or you can compare strings by using regular expressions by calling one of the functions `ereg()`, `eregi()` with your own pattern!

Comment: Re *"If you use it to compare strings, you are comparing a string with a regular expression to find a perfect match!"*: Are you sure about that? That would mean the operator would not be [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) (in all cases). That sounds highly unlikely. Can provide you a source and/or an example here to back up your statement? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1858708/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

`eq` in PHP would be news to me but there is the strict comparison operator

```
$a === $b
```

check [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for details.

Comment: I assume he means "binary" in the sense that it takes too argument or has two results (compared to, say, the Perl cmp operator) but the word "binary" has some unfortunate ambiguities in this context (eg bitwise vs logical comparison).

Comment: My mistake, I meant "strict". Revised.